# Is possible to know which platform version of universal app user has?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to develop service for synchronising user specific data within installations of my app. For instance, I have in-app consumable purchase in my app, lets say credits for a game. I need these credits to be shared between both mobile and desktop version of the application. But if user has only mobile or only desktop version, it is waste of resources to store historical purchase records for synchronisation. Current credits amount should be enough.

Maybe not really good example but should do for illustration. So is possible to know if user has both platform versions or he has only mobile/desktop version? Is there any proper API I would touch for the information from sync service or from the app?

Thanks for answers in regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is possible to know if user has both platform versions or he has only mobile/desktop version?

There is no official existing API to meet your entire requirement directly, but you can handle it by yourself. Using [`AnalyticsVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo.aspx) class to get the type of device the application is running on, especially the [`AnalyticsVersionInfo.DeviceFamily`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo.devicefamily.aspx) property.

For different platform, you can decide how to sync up your records.